# How to get recently viewed product collection in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to get the recently viewed product collection directly from model without using block function.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: @Shoaib Munir updated my post

Answer (score 4):

It can get Recently viewed product collection in magento2 without using its block

```
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $recentlyViewedClass = \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Viewed::class;
        $_recentlyViewedProductCollection = $_objectManager->create($recentlyViewedClass)->getCollection();
        $_recentlyViewedProductCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                        ->setPageSize(10) // load 10 products
                                        ->load();

        echo 'Recently Viewed Products Count  : ' . $_recentlyViewedProductCollection->getSize() . PHP_EOL;

        if($_recentlyViewedProductCollection->getSize() > 0 )   {
            foreach($_recentlyViewedProductCollection as $_product) {
                echo $_product->getSku() .' | '. $_product->getName() . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
```

Comment: But its returning not only recently viewed product, also all products

Comment: I was looking for this solution to get collection from model instead of block. Thanks :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
use Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Factory;
$model = $this->indexFactory->get('viewed');
        $collection = $model->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setCustomerId($customerId);


$collection->excludeProductIds($productId)
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->setPageSize(($noOfProductsToDisplay ? $noOfProductsToDisplay : 5))
                ->setCurPage(1);

            $collection->setAddedAtOrder()
                ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
```

Comment: Thanks Mano M. +1 :)

Comment: i am still getting all products don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<?php 
namespace PackageName\ModuleName\Block\RecentlyViewed;

class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $recentlyViewed;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
        parent::__construct( $context, $data );
    }

    public function getMostRecentlyViewed(){
        return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection()->getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . but i need to achieve this in api . so i want to get recently viewed product collection without using block function.

Answer (score 0):

recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
    } 
    public function getMostRecentlyViewed()
    {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $recentlyViewedClass = \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Viewed::class;
    $recentlyViewedProductCollection = $objectManager->create($recentlyViewedClass)->getCollection();
    $recentlyViewedProductCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                    ->setPageSize(5) // load 10 products
                                    ->load();

    if($recentlyViewedProductCollection->getSize() > 0 )   {
     
        $internalItems['message'] = "";
        foreach($recentlyViewedProductCollection as $item) {
            $data[]= $item->getData();
            $internalItems['data'] = $data;
        }
        echo json_encode($internalItems);
        die;
    }
}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
get recent viewed product in magento programmatically / for api also
```

use Larsonjuhl\MobileApi\Api\Customer\RecentViewedInterface;

class RecentViewed implements RecentViewedInterface
{

protected $recentlyViewed;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
} 
public function getMostRecentlyViewed()
{
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$recentlyViewedClass = \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Viewed::class;
$recentlyViewedProductCollection = $objectManager->create($recentlyViewedClass)->getCollection();
$recentlyViewedProductCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->setPageSize(5) // load 10 products
                                ->load();

if($recentlyViewedProductCollection->getSize() > 0 )   {
 
    $internalItems['message'] = "";
    foreach($recentlyViewedProductCollection as $item) {
        $data[]= $item->getData();
        $internalItems['data'] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($internalItems);
    die;
}
```

}
}