# Magento 2 - Recently viewed product collection from Model

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, collection, products, recently-viewed

**Please read description carefully before marking it as duplicate**

I want to get recently viewed product collection from **Model** instead of **Block**

I have check similar post but no one answered it correctly
[How to get recently viewed product collection in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262074/how-to-get-recently-viewed-product-collection-in-magento2)

Comment: do you need this for admin or frontend? And for login customer?

Comment: I need it on frontend for all customers combined list of recently viewed products

Comment: But generally Magento show current customer recently view products.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible that I can get all recently viewed combined data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution of this

In my Class

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Viewed $recentlyViewedModel,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->recentlyViewedModel = $recentlyViewedModel;
    ...
}

public function getRecentlyViewedCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->recentlyViewedModel->getCollection();
    $collection->setPageSize(20)
        ->setCurPage(1);

    return $collection->load();
}
```

It is working fine and I am getting whole customers combined recently viewed products collection from Model.

Comment: this is not working for me... i am getting All products..